# Serve static folder using nodejs and express js

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to serve static files using nodejs and express js. In the code I have:

```
server.use('/public', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

But when I try to enter locahost:myPort/public i get

```
Cannot GET /public/
```

I have some two other mappings: "/search.html" and "/download.html" and those pages works fine. What I would like to get is the files list, which are in the public folder.

Is it possible to get such results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is possible through the use of the `serve-index` middleware.
https://github.com/expressjs/serve-index

```
npm install serve-index
```

.

```
var serveIndex = require('serve-index');

app.use('/public', serveIndex('/public'));
```